# Cygwin's tr command, "tr -s [:blank:] ' '", replacing instances of lowercase 'a' in text file

Tags: cygwin, tr

On my Windows system, when I use Cygwin's tr command to remove white space from a text file, like so

type ..\item\query.out| tr -s [:blank:] ' ' > ..\item\a

I find that, in addition to removing white space, all instances of lowercase 'a' have been replaced with spaces.

Does anyone know why this should be and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing, though I could not use `type`, instead I used: `cat ..\item\query.out| tr -s [:blank:] ' ' > ..\item\a` and all the a's remained.

Comment: I can't reproduce anything like that.  What does `type ..\item\query.out` alone output?

Answer (score 0):

`type` is not the command to do what you think. Use `cat` instead

```
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type cat
cat is /usr/bin/cat
$ echo "prova prova" > /tmp/test.txt

$ cat /tmp/test.txt
prova prova

$ cat /tmp/test.txt | tr -d [:blank:]
provaprova
```